# Explanation of hacked code on a site

Tags: php

I found this code on a hacked site, what does it do exactly? It appears to mess with some file permissions, how can it allow an attacker entry?

http://pastebin.com/jFaFdyKQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this isn't that evil... Are you sure this is the 'hacked' part?

As you can see the bottom few lines are commented out, so they don't do anything. The only 'active' code lines are:

```
system('chmod -R 744 *');
system('find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;');
```

The system() function executes a command on the server itself. So you have to look to the commands given, which are unix commands:

```
chmod -R 744 *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

The first line says; change the file permissions recursively (everything in this working directory, including it's children) to modus 744 (all-read-read).
The second line finds all directories in the current working directory and changes the modus to 755, which is in fact standard for directories (and equivalent to `chmod +X -R ./*`, when executed directly after the first command)

To be honest, I don't see any harm done, as directories get the standard permissions, files only some extra permissions for the owner of the file. It would be dangerous when also group and world would get all permissions...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this command line is used to install a Magento plugin

`system('./pear install -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest');`

Looks to me it's nothing to do with attacking anything, more it's a installer for [this](http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-install-magento-extensions-magento-extension-installation-guide/) plugin

e: But hey, I don't know much about PHP, just Magento is mentioned, I did a search for that command line and found the plugin and it's setting file permissions and stuff. So, safe to assume it's safe, right?

Comment: That line is actually commented out in the php file

Comment: So it is. Hey, I said I don't know PHP, my answer was based more on logic.

Answer (score 0):

The last few lines are commented out `/*   */` the only lines that are executed are :

```
system('chmod -R 744 *'); 
system('find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;');
```

[chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) changes permissions to files / directories on Linux / Unix / OSX based operating systems.

The first command changed permissions on all files from the current directory recursively (-R) to 744 and the second command changes all directories in the current directory recursively to 755

Answer (score 0):

In general this code changed permission for files to 755 so some files can be run by outside word, not only by the internal scripts.

And here is code that is disabled, so probably hacker disabled possibility to install any updates for magento shop:

```
/*   /////
system('./pear mage-setup');
system('./pear install -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest');

//system('chmod -R 744 *');
//system('find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;');

*/
```